# How can I resolve Time Out Error when installing Tensorflow in Command Prompt

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, installation, command-prompt

I currently have installed Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:54:40) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32. I also have Anaconda installed with its own python version.

I am trying to install tensorflow with below code (also tried pip install tensorflow). I have successfully installed nltk, numpy and tflearn. I am now trying to install tensorflow and the following message is what I get. I have trying several times over the past hour but I keep getting the same error at different points (percentage completed).

C:\Windows\system32>pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow

Collecting tensorflow

Downloading tensorflow-2.1.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (355.9 MB)
|██████████████████████████████  | 336.2 MB 251 kB/s eta 0:01:19

ERROR: Exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File.....

....

socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

....

raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.") 
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', 
port=443): Read timed out.

Comment: Did you make sure you use the right proxy? E.g. If you have a firewall at your office, you often need to use a proxy to install modules with pip.

Comment: No proxy. It is my own personal computer at home.

Comment: Are you trying to use Conda for this? You really should, especially since you're on Windows.

Comment: I also tried using conda but had issues installing tflearn. When I installed it using 'pip install tflearn' I got 'Successfully installed Pillow-7.1.1 tflearn-0.3.2'. But when I ran my python file in conda I got a response 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib' regarding the line import tflearn in my file. (tensorflow was installed successfully.)

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that issue was indeed the speed of my internet. I downloaded it when the internet was much faster and it downloaded completely.